# How do I integrate my canvas app in lightning

Tags: lightning, canvas, iframe

I have a canvas app (iframe) working perfectly in SalesForce Classic.  How do I integrate it into Lightning?

Answer (score 1):

You use the [force:canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:canvasApp/documentation) tag. The example from the documentation is:

```
<aura:component>
    <force:canvasApp developerName="MyCanvasApp" namespacePrefix="myNamespace" />
</aura:component>
```

---

Custom component you can use in any builder:

---

## canvas.component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="namespace" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="developerName" type="String" />
    <force:canvasApp developerName="{!v.developerName}" namespacePrefix="{!v.namespace}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

## canvas.design

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute required="false" name="namespace" />
    <design:attribute required="true" name="developerName" />
</design:component>
```

---

Example Usage:

[image: Example of canvas in builder]

---

Comment: How do you enable that component in Lighting?

Comment: @Rob You write a custom component, then add it to a Lightning Page. You will need to add additional logic depending on exactly where you want to place the component.

Comment: Can you provide a URL that steps a developer through the process?  Its the 'add it to a Lightning Page' that is not documented, haven't found any docs yet.

Comment: @Rob Start here, I guess? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_intro.htm

Comment: there is no mention of integrating a canvas app into lightning there.

Comment: @Rob Right. You make a component that holds the force:canvasApp, then add *that* component to a page.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no documentation on how to integrate force:canvasApp from the Developer Console.  If someone can provide a url to a tutorial that shows how to integrate a canvas app in lightning that would be great.

Comment: @Rob sorry, was mobile for a bit. Added a fully self-contained example.